# Capybara ends up with inconsistent results on websockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am experiencing flaky action cable tests on capybara backed by cuprite(headless mode). Basically, I am creating a post using action cable and setting it on React using Mobx. I ran the test 150 times in a loop and it failed 30 times. What can cause this inconsistent failure?

If I make the driver go to another page or reload the same page the post appears as expected.

The settings are as follow:

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'rails_helper.rb'

Dir[File.join(__dir__, "system/support/**/*.rb")].sort.each { |file| require file }

module CupriteHelpers
   # some test helpers
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include CupriteHelpers, type: :system
end
```

spec/system/support/capybara.rb

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
Capybara.default_normalize_ws = true
Capybara.save_path = ENV.fetch("CAPYBARA_ARTIFACTS", "./tmp/capybara")

Capybara.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  attr_accessor :last_used_session
  
  def using_session(name, &block)
    self.last_used_session = name
    super
  ensure
    self.last_used_session = nil
  end
end)
```

spec/system/support/curprite.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver(:cuprite) do |app|
  Capybara::Cuprite::Driver.new(
    app,
    **{
      window_size: [1440, 900],
      browser_options: {},
      process_timeout: 60,
      timeout: 15,
      inspector: ENV['INSPECTOR'] == 'true',
      headless: !ENV['HEADLESS'].in?(%w[n 0 no false]),
      slowmo: (0.2 if ENV['HEADLESS'].in?(%w[n 0 no false])),
      js_errors: false,
      logger: FerrumLogger.new
    }
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver = :cuprite
```

spec/system/post_spec.rb

```
    it 'can create a new post and the creator is the user do
      click_button 'Add New Post +'
      expect(page).to have_css('#post-2')
      # rest of the tests but the line above fails
    end
```

Comment: maybe you need to wait long enough for cable connection establish: `expect(page).to have_css('#post-2', wait: 5)`

Comment: @LamPhan this doesn't really help. I tried to use wait, sleep and max wait time.

Comment: @BartuDemirkiran trying to fix this problem with wait/sleep is bad practice it is only going to make your test set even more flanky. Could you share a bit more context on what the `click_button 'Add New Post +'` should render?

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos I was just trying different ways to fix the problem. `sleep` didn't help at all. Basically, it posts the request to the server. And we broadcast the change to the mobx store. Mobx should be catching that.

Comment: @BartuDemirkiran you could test action cable as proposed in [rails guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#channel-test-case).

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos I am doing a system(e2e) check and it fails. Testing AC is working as expected.

Comment: @BartuDemirkiran can you add a bit more context on how you set up the spec. And why you need `expect(page).to have_css('#post-2')` as the first expect block?

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos that's the row that I am adding. That's getting generated in the given div. So I had to check this.

Comment: @BartuDemirkiran I suspect your problem is a common one - you are clicking the button before the Javascript is fully set up. Solutions to that problem are (a) to do an initial expectation that checks that the page is fully loaded before clicking things (if there is such a way) or (b) to have the button initially disabled and have the Javascript enable it when everything is ready, then Capybara should wait for the button to be enabled if you try to click it.